# Align bars of bar graph to the left on the labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I would like to position the bars in `geom_bar` so that the x-axis label is to the left of the bar not the center

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
      x = c(1,1,4,4,8,8),
      y = c("A","B","A","B","A","B"), 
      z = c(10,5,20,2,8,4),
      a = c(1,1,4,4,2,2)
)

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=z,fill=y,width=a)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity", alpha=.6) +    
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can just move the bars by half their width:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x + a/2, y = z, fill = y, width = a)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity", alpha = .6) +    
  scale_x_continuous(name = "x", breaks = 0:10)
```

[image]